# Reverse a sentence and print each word in reverse order in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm making a JavaScript program where if a user inputs a sting such as

```
"i love my country"
```

the output will produce:

```
country
my
love
i
```

I have tried using `split` function but not getting the required output.

```
<script language="javascript">
    var n, x, i, j;
    rev = "";
    n = window.prompt("enter any string");
    x = n.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        for (j = x[i].length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            document.writeln(x[i].charAt(j));
            document.write(rev);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Share what have you tried so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For the edit conflicts on this post and his answers: the question and all this answers were coming through the LQP review queue because of the non neutral string, this is why I edited it out.

Comment: @vard "i love my country" appear neutral , here . Would "i love my cats" also be considered non-neutral ?

Comment: @guest271314 Depends of how you see it, but it's not really relevant anyway - as the q&a here were all considered LQP I fixed them with a minor change so they don't come up in the queue like so.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Array.prototype.reverse()` , `Array.prototype.join()`

```js
var str = "I LOVE MY COUNTRY";
console.log(str.split(/\s/).reverse().join(" "));
```

---

Remove `()` at `j = x[i].length()` ; `.length` is not a function ; adding `document.write("<br>")` below inner `for` loop to include `<br>` tag in output after each iteration of `i` to place line break in `html` following a word entered at `prompt` . E.g., try input of "I love my country" at `prompt()` at stacksnippets

```js
var n, x, i, j;
rev = "";
n = window.prompt("enter any string");
x = n.split(" ");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  for (j = x[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    document.writeln(x[i].charAt(j));
  }
  document.write("<br>")
}
```

Comment: @varshaDas See updated post

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
var str = "SAMPLE STRING";
alert( str.split( "\\s+" ).reverse.join ( " " ) );
alert( str.split( " " ).reverse.join ( " " ) );
```

Since you want to print in a new line

```
var str = "SAMPLE STRING";
alert( str.split( " " ).reverse.join ( "\n" ) );
```

Comment: thank you sir...it is working

Comment: @varshaDas you are welcome, please don't forget to upvote and select the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str  = "SAMPLE STRING";

var arr = str.split(" ");

arr.reverse();

str = arr.join(" ");
```

Comment: yes it is working but i want to print each word in new line

Comment: @varshaDas in that case just use a for loop on `arr` after reverse and print each element

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "SAMPLE STRING"
a.split(" ").reverse().forEach(function(element) {
    document.writeln(element);
    document.write('<br />')  
})
```

OUTPUT:

```
STRING 
SAMPLE
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tr7h50v1/)

Comment: thanks for the code but i would like to print each word in new line....how to do it?

Comment: @varshaDas i have updated the code for the required output